# root view controllers and push

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Good day! There are 5 view controllers that i have. One of them i want to push from UITableView cell like this:

```
Contacts *detailViewController = [[Contacts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Contacts" bundle:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
```

in appDelegate i did manage to add root view controllers like this:

```
mainView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MainViewController" bundle: nil]];

secondView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[SearchController alloc] initWithNibName: @"SearchController" bundle: nil]];

thirdView  = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[CitySearch alloc] initWithNibName: @"CitySearch" bundle: nil]];

forthView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MessengerMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessengerMenu" bundle:nil]];

fifthView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[Contacts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Contacts" bundle:nil]];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: mainView ,secondView, thirdView, forthView, fifthView, nil];

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

but self.navigationController in Messenger viewController is still null and push does not happen.

What do i do wrong?

Comment: Is there `Messenger` and `MessengerMenu` the same controller?

Comment: is strange, see the self.rootViewController this can clear situation

Comment: it seem no wrong in your code :(

Comment: @Pavel oh, I mean check self.parentViewController to see from where you navigate and what to do, and if parent have navigationController you can use it  to push

Comment: Show your more code...of .h file...

Comment: self.window.rootViewController is <UITabBarController: 0x16daa150>

Comment: Where did you add your push your view controller? The above which is placed in MessengerMenu controller or other than that?

Comment: Show the .h file of your controller where you are adding push code

Comment: interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    
}

property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

Comment: How you are declaring mainView

Comment: UINavigationController  *mainView, *secondView, *thirdView;

Comment: Show the error, if any you are getting

Comment: what did you do with property (strong, nonatomic)  UINavigationController *navigationController;

Comment: i do nothing with UINavigationController *navigationController; just declare and synthesize

Comment: set selected [tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3]; in tab bar controller...

Comment: yes, it works. but other views does not :(

Comment: [tabbarController setViewController:array]; instead of tabBarController.viewController.

Answer (score 0):

You should make alloc all viewController using `UIViewController` and add them to tabbarController.

if, you want one of them as navigationController, just put it a

Now NavigationController's root controller can be made to tabBarController.

```
mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MainViewController" bundle: nil];

secondView = [[SearchController alloc] initWithNibName: @"SearchController" bundle: nil];

thirdView  = [CitySearch alloc] initWithNibName: @"CitySearch" bundle: nil];

forthView = [[MessengerMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessengerMenu" bundle:nil];

self.navigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:forthView];
fifthView = [[Contacts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Contacts" bundle:nil]];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: mainView ,secondView, thirdView, forthView, fifthView, nil];



[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

Comment: he want to add each tab is one navigation controller

Comment: didn't help. there is something else. i did try to do only one controller [self.window setRootViewController:fourthView]; it works. but when there are many controllers in tabBar it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this alloc init method for creating  NSArray of viewcontrollers,

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: mainView ,secondView, thirdView, forthView, fifthView, nil];
```

Or You fist create the UITabbarViewController ,set it to rootVC:

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

then:

```
mainView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: 
[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MainViewController" bundle: nil]];
 secondView =[[SearchController alloc] initWithNibName: @"SearchController" bundle: nil];
 thirdView  = [[CitySearch  alloc] initWithNibName: @"CitySearch" bundle: nil];
 forthView = [[MessengerMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessengerMenu" bundle:nil];
fifthView = [[Contacts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Contacts" bundle:nil];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: mainView ,secondView, thirdView, forthView, fifthView, nil];
```

Comment: still null in  '- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here, for example:
    // Create the next view controller.
    Contacts *detailViewController = [[Contacts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Contacts" bundle:nil];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController);
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
}
'

Answer (score 0):

Hope It will work....

```
mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MainViewController" bundle: nil];

secondView = [[SearchController alloc] initWithNibName: @"SearchController" bundle: nil];

thirdView  = [CitySearch alloc] initWithNibName: @"CitySearch" bundle: nil];

forthView = [[MessengerMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessengerMenu" bundle:nil];


UINavigationController *navmain = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainView];

UINavigationController *navSecond = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondView];

UINavigationController *navThird = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:thirdView];

UINavigationController *navFourth = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:forthView];
    //Second, third, fourth...

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:navmain, navSecond, navThird, navFourth, nil];
        [tabBarController setViewControllers:array];

//and set selectedIndex
    [tabBarController setSelectedindex:2];
```

Comment: it works, but other views doesn't. it's only thirdView presented

Comment: they are not presented at all

Comment: i did like you post. NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController); is null

Comment: Can you edit your code again with what you are exactly using now?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wrong in adding viewController? I add controller like subview to main view on pushing a button like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonMessagePressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    messController = [[MessengerMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessengerMenu" bundle:nil];
    [messController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 300, 200)];

    for (UIView *theView in self.currenWeatherView.subviews) {
        [theView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [self.currenWeatherView addSubview: messController.view];
}
```